# Can faces be considered sexual?

Tags: sex

Let's say there's a culture of people which never show their faces, except from when eating, but they only uncover their mouths and only with family.
Otherwise they never show their faces to anyone.
Would then people develop to view faces as sexual?

I've seen documentaries of villages where women wander around fully naked and men don't seem aroused about that.
So I'd imagine breasts and any body part don't cause arousal in per se... But the situation causes arousal.
But I never studied human sexuality cause I've was uninterested in that and considered it way to boring so I might be also totally wrong.

I also heard that french people used to be aroused by ankles because women never showed their legs in public, but might also be something based on mythology.... Honestly everything I know about sex is that one lesson in school 17 years or so ago.
Which isn't much....

I also know how sexual selection works in nature like "tall guy = guy strong or smart enough to find  food to grow tall = sexy"

But this post is about unnatural sexual selection.

One could say muslim people make a good real life example, but in our world muslim men can see women with their faces uncovered on the daily due to globalization... And in my country it is illegal to go around with a covered face, so I don't know if there are any muslims here, and if there are... They can't go around with a covered face,due to terrorism laws.

Comment: Rule 34: "If it exists, or can be imagined, there is porn of it"... so yes, that would include faces.

Comment: This appears to be a real world psychology question.  You may get a better answer on the Psychology and Neuroscience SE - the question has probably been studied in the countries you mention in times and places where there was not ready access to imagery of human faces.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this belongs on another site in the stack exchange (but that option only lets me pick the meta) I think it belongs with Psychology and Neuroscience SE

Comment: I don't mind this post as much. So the op is no expert in sex. Most posters here don't know a thing about what they're asking and the general standard in this se is very low. It's an established joke that hiding makes things sexual. Most posts here are just random, at least this question has some foundation in pop culture. I'd argue above average question. People need to stop taking their expertise for granted. Most questions fit multiple stack exchanges. I notice this pattern, when people are experts because simple topic, questions get closed.

Comment: Hiding the face is a pretty common fetish in current BDSM. Google "sensory deprivation hood" (NSFW). The hood makes the wearer anonymous and dehumanises them "freeing" the other person from social norms, and the person in the hood cant sense what's happening (more anticipation) and has heightened sense of touch.

Comment: Is this question inspired by the current mask mandate?

Answer (score 2):

Culture can sexualize anything.  In some religious traditions, women are supposed to cover their hair, so as not to "distract" men, and hair is about as far as you can get from an erogenous zone. In that context, a few strands of hair showing under a hat or scarf can become something transgressive.

So yes, I would say that, in a culture where covering one's face in public was the expected norm, showing the face could easily become sexualized.

Comment: I don't think "sexualization"  and attraction are the same thing... Wikipedia says 50% of humans are turned on by biting but I don't know any culture who sexualizes teeth

Comment: @user82040 sexuality is contextual and not binary. It's not either one or the other. I know straight male gynecologists that say the vagina on a patient is as sexual as a hand. A face can be as sexual as anything and something you might consider sexual is not to other people. I don't want to get too explicit here, but faces take an active or passive part in very popular sexual activities. Anything involved in sex can be sexual to people just visually as well. Your op is a bit cliche with the old Seinfeld joke that hiding makes it sexual. That's an oversimplification